# Is there a browser based interface for running command line on your host?

Tags: command-line, browser, php, web

I know I can manually run it through PHP's exec() command but I was hoping if there was a ready to download and deploy PHP-based system that could act as a bridge and terminal and you can run commands on it like you were in the terminal itself.

Comment: I did try searching but I always get the reverse, running PHP via command line. What I need is running command line via PHP. Sad for the downvote :(

Comment: The right terms to search were probably PHP and shell, not command line. Found http://sourceforge.net/directory/terminals/virtual/language:php/os:windows/

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Why not connect via, say, ssh?

Comment: Paid web hosting provider disabled SSH and only provides it for the more expensive business plan :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [PHPShell](http://phpshell.sourceforge.net/). I tried it and it works great. Although it can't use vim or any program that requires user input in the middle of execution but that's enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

Kloxo has a command line interface, you can use it

check [ssh.serverdo.in](https://ssh.serverdo.in/), and [serfish](http://www.serfish.com/console/), i used those in the past, or you can just google "online ssh client".

PS: I don't think you can find a php script that acts like a terminal, i think you should go for java.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't run Kloxo, it requires root access.

Comment: @radj please read my edit

Comment: I found PHPShell http://phpshell.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @radj sir,you stated that "Paid web hosting provider disabled SSH and only provides it for the more expensive business plan ", may i ask you what

Comment: I'm on [iFastNet's premium hosting](https://ifastnet.com/portal/sharedhosting.php). The business hosting is on the next tab.

Comment: @radj you can go for justhost, very cheap with ssh, just [validate your purchase](https://my.justhost.com/cgi/help/verify) and [enable ssh](https://my.justhost.com/cgi/help/180#enable) justhost.com or hostgator.com are very cheap and reliable, they offer ssh, many companies offer ssh, for example i have a vps with pacifichost.com but they seem to have ssh with the [shared hosing plan](http://www.pacifichost.com/reseller-hosting.shtml)

Comment: Wow. Thanks for these! Cheaper and with R/RoR, too! I've been with this host for 5 years and the dependence on SSH just started this year.